# What is recursive relationship, and how is it calculated?

Tags: probability, expected-value, recursion

I understand neither Brilliant's explanations nor your explanations of Brilliant's explanations, but since I've nowhere else to go, I'll ask your help again. What on earth is recursive relationship, and how is it calculated, what's the formula? Walk me through, but please do it so that I understand it this time. I tried Brilliant to boost my skills and confidence, but its highest achievement so far is making me feel dumb and hopeless (believe it or not, I used to be very good at math at school, or so it was believed)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: "I understand neither Brilliant's explanations nor your explanations of Brilliant's explanations." Well, what was unclear about my explanation to your last question?

Comment: If you want to ask this question again it would be good if you can tell us your mathematics background. That will help us tailor the answer. I can't tell you how many times I have seen someone ask for a reference for high school algebra and get a reference to abstract algebra because they weren't specific enough about their background.